# Blazor @onkeypress of a text box doesn't work in IE?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm creating a server-side blazor application and have the following razor file.

```
@page "/test"
@using BlazorApp2.Data
@inject ViewModels.TestViewModel VM

<div>
    Search:
    <input id="search" type="text" @bind="VM.Search" @onkeypress="@VM.SearchChanged" />
    <span>@VM.Search</span>
</div>
```

**ViewModels.TestViewModel:**

```
public string Search { get; set; }

public async void SearchChanged()
{
    // Break point set but not hit?
}
```

Typing in the text box "search" doesn't hit the break point set in `SearchChanged()` when in IE? It works in Chrome.

Comment: I made a [fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/yjwhub6d) of this and it works fine

Comment: It turns out it doesn't work in IE only.

Comment: Server-side Blazor can be made to work in IE11 with polyfills. Read more [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can miss registering TestViewModel in Startup.ConfigureServices

You can visit this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0 to refer more.

If you want Blazor run on IE11, please add Polyfills. Visit this link: https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill to refer more.

You can download Polyfills at here: https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill/releases

Here is a sample following your question. Hope to help, my friend :))

1) Models

```
namespace BlazorApp.Models
{
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public string Search { get; set; }

        public async void SearchChanged()
        {
            // Break point set but not hit?
            Search = "Hello world";            
        }
    }
}
```

2) In Startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
            services.AddSingleton<Models.TestViewModel>();
        }
```

3)View

```
@page "/testview"
@inject Models.TestViewModel VM

<h1>Test Blazor</h1>
<div>
    Search:
    <input id="search" type="text" @bind="VM.Search" @onkeypress="@VM.SearchChanged" />
    <span>@VM.Search</span>
</div>
```

4) In _Host view

```
@page "/"
@namespace BlazorApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlazorApp</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
    </app>

    <script src="~/scripts/blazor.polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `@inject Models.TestViewModel VM` would break the component at runtime if he forgot to register it, the component would not render. So this can't be it.

Comment: @Tewr, Yes, the VM is regestered.

Comment: It turns out it doesn't run in IE. It works in Chrome.

Comment: @ca9163d9: Sorry my friend for the late response. As Tewr's advice, you need to add polyfill to run Blazor on IE (11). I updated my solution. Please check it.